# Apache mod_rewrite isn't working outside virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.4

When I use my mod_rewrite rules directly inside httpd.conf, it doesn't work. When I use it inside an virtualhost block, it works as it should. It was working before, but now it doesn't, I wonder what the problem is. Is mod_rewrite supposed to not work directly?

### mod_alias redirect works wherever I place that, but mod_rewrite doesn't work when it is placed directly in httpd.conf

My httpd.conf file is:

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/access_log"
# with ServerRoot set to "/usr/local/apache2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log", whereas "/logs/access_log" 
# will be interpreted as '/logs/access_log'.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"

#
# Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
# for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
#
# Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
# mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
# other reason.
#
# Mutex default:logs

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
#LoadModule authnz_fcgi_module modules/mod_authnz_fcgi.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
#LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module modules/mod_cache_socache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
#LoadModule socache_redis_module modules/mod_socache_redis.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
#LoadModule example_hooks_module modules/mod_example_hooks.so
#LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
#LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
#LoadModule example_ipc_module modules/mod_example_ipc.so
#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
#LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
#LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_uwsgi_module modules/mod_proxy_uwsgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_fdpass_module modules/mod_proxy_fdpass.so
#LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule proxy_hcheck_module modules/mod_proxy_hcheck.so
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
#LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule optional_hook_export_module modules/mod_optional_hook_export.so
#LoadModule optional_hook_import_module modules/mod_optional_hook_import.so
#LoadModule optional_fn_import_module modules/mod_optional_fn_import.so
#LoadModule optional_fn_export_module modules/mod_optional_fn_export.so
#LoadModule dialup_module modules/mod_dialup.so
LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
#LoadModule proxy_http2_module modules/mod_proxy_http2.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
#LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
#LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
#LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
#ServerAdmin you@example.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
#DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
#<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    #AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    #Require all granted
#</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.phtml default.htm default.html home.htm
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    #ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    #
    # Avoid passing HTTP_PROXY environment to CGI's on this or any proxied
    # backend servers which have lingering "httpoxy" defects.
    # 'Proxy' request header is undefined by the IETF, not listed by IANA
    #
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
# returning the entire resource, or one of the special
# values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
# Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
#MaxRanges unlimited

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

TraceEnable Off

ServerTokens Full
ServerSignature On

ProxyErrorOverride On

<FilesMatch "\.html|.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000"
</FilesMatch>

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

IncludeOptional conf/custom/*.conf

Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
```

Files in the `custom` folder:
dir.conf

```
<Directory "/home/username/public_html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

extra-settings.conf

```
TimeOut 60

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

UseCanonicalName Off

AccessFileName .htaccess

HostnameLookups Off

<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
  RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers             3
    MinSpareThreads         75
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    ThreadsPerChild         25
    MaxRequestWorkers      1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

ServerLimit 1000
```

virtualhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin support@myemailisprivate.com
DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html
</VirtualHost>

Listen 443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin support@myemailisprivate.com
DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html
SSLEngine On
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
SSLCertificateFile "/home/username/ssl/localhost.crt"
SSLcertificateKeyFile "/home/username/ssl/localhost.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

My mod_rewrite code is:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On

#Double redirects for HSTS preload

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://mydomain\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://www\.mydomain\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
#Doesn't work when directly added to httpd.conf or when I include it from an external file, only works inside the <virtualhost> block, also tried using the directory block, but no luck as well
```

Comment: Both [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) works in  the server config context. As you don't share any of the relevant configuration, it's impossible to answer, and we could only guess. Maybe you are missing the [`RewriteEngine on`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine), as the default for it is `off`.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Done, sorry

Comment: it still seems to be outside of the `<server>` blocks.

Comment: @Jasen ?? what? I have recompiled Apache plenty of times, but no good

Comment: @Jasen: the [`server { }`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) blocks are related to Nginx. This is Apache 2.4.

Comment: @EsaJokinen yea, ok

Comment: oops, I meant `<vitualhost>`

Comment: I have recompiled Apache plenty of times, but no good, deleted the complete apache folder, but no

Comment: @Jasen, shouldn't it work outside virtualhost?

Comment: for any requests not covered by virtualhost i guess it would work.

Comment: @Jasen, nope, not even for the requests without virtualhost, mod_alias works in every way lol. Try my conf maybe, and tell me if it works for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for the [`RewriteEngine` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> Note that rewrite configurations are not inherited by virtual hosts.
>   This means that you need to have a `RewriteEngine on` directive for each
>   virtual host in which you wish to use rewrite rules.

It's possible to inherit the rules from parent configuration using `RewriteOptions Inherit`:

> `Inherit` This forces the current configuration to inherit the
>   configuration of the parent. In per-virtual-server context, this means
>   that the maps, conditions and rules of the main server are inherited.
>   - - The inherited rules are virtually copied to the section where this directive is being used. If used in combination with local rules, the
>   inherited rules are copied behind the local rules.

As both would go to the `<VirtualHost>` block anyways, this would make your configuration even more complicated, so I wouldn't recommend that.

You must notice your `RewriteCond`s and `RewriteRule`s are both related to a single name based virtual host. Therefore, there shouldn't be any need to make them global. In fact, performing unnecessary mod_rewrite tests can cause unnecessary overhead to your server.

However, it would be way more efficient to use [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) `Redirect`s, instead. Also, the comment suggest you are using "#Double redirects for HSTS preload", but the www subdomain redirects to the domain apex. If all your subdomains can inherit the HSTS policy, you don't need the additional redirect. E.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>

    DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So thanks for your time

Comment: `RewriteOptions Inherit` for the win (joking)